# How to extract images of a video file on Android?

Tags: android, video, android-bitmap

A short question:

Suppose you have a video file that is supported on the device (available [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), for example).

How would you get an image (or a number of images) of a specific time of the video, to be saved into a Bitmap instance?

Is it also possible to set what size the bitmap would be (so that it won't take a lot of memory, in case the video is of high resolution) ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142348/extract-video-frames-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap =ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/video.mp4",MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: This does not get a bitmap of a given time of the video, as I've written: "... of a specific time". All images that I'll take this way will be the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188938/how-to-get-the-frame-from-video-file-in-android

Comment: so this is the correct one: MediaMetadataRetriever ? or should I use FFMPEG  ?