# Can not get camera output, face detection android

Tags: android, face-detection, google-vision

I am trying face detection and adding mask(graphic overlay) using google vision api ,the problem is i could not get the ouptut from camera after detecting and adding mask.so far I have tried this solution from github , https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/24 ,based on this issue i have added a custom detector class,
[Mobile Vision API - concatenate new detector object to continue frame processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299947/mobile-vision-api-concatenate-new-detector-object-to-continue-frame-processing/32314136) .  and added this on mydetector class [How to create Bitmap from grayscaled byte buffer image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412197/how-to-create-bitmap-from-grayscaled-byte-buffer-image/33054982#33054982) .

MyDetectorClass

```
class MyFaceDetector extends Detector<Face> 
{
    private Detector<Face> mDelegate;

    MyFaceDetector(Detector<Face> delegate) {
        mDelegate = delegate;
    }

    public SparseArray<Face> detect(Frame frame) {
        // *** add your custom frame processing code here
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = frame.getGrayscaleImageData();
        byte[] bytes = byteBuffer.array();
        int w = frame.getMetadata().getWidth();
        int h = frame.getMetadata().getHeight();
        YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(bytes, ImageFormat.NV21, w, h, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, w, h), 100, baos); // Where 100 is the quality of the generated jpeg
        byte[] jpegArray = baos.toByteArray();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegArray, 0, jpegArray.length);
        Log.e("got bitmap","bitmap val " + bitmap);
        return mDelegate.detect(frame);
    }

    public boolean isOperational() {
        return mDelegate.isOperational();
    }

    public boolean setFocus(int id) {
        return mDelegate.setFocus(id);
    }
}
```

frame processing

```
public SparseArray<Face> detect(Frame frame) 
{
    // *** add your custom frame processing code here
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = frame.getGrayscaleImageData();
    byte[] bytes = byteBuffer.array();
    int w = frame.getMetadata().getWidth();
    int h = frame.getMetadata().getHeight();
    YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(bytes, ImageFormat.NV21, w, h, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, w, h), 100, baos); // Where 100 is the quality of the generated jpeg
    byte[] jpegArray = baos.toByteArray();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegArray, 0, jpegArray.length);
    Log.e("got bitmap","bitmap val " + bitmap);
    return mDelegate.detect(frame);
}
```

i am getting a rotated bitmap ,that is without the mask (graphic overlay) i have added .How can i get the camera output with mask .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: You can't.

Why? Android camera output frames in NV21 ByteBuffer. And you must generate your masks based on the landmarks points in a separated Bitmap, then join them.
Sorry but, that's how the Android Camera API work. Nothing can be done. You must do it manually.

Also, I wouldn't get the camera preview then convert it to YuvImage then to Bitmap. That process consumes **a lot** of resources and makes preview **very very slow**. Instead I would use this method which will be a lot faster and rotates your preview internally so you don't loose time doing it:

```
outputFrame = new Frame.Builder().setImageData(mPendingFrameData, mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.NV21)
              .setId(mPendingFrameId)
              .setTimestampMillis(mPendingTimeMillis)
              .setRotation(mRotation)
              .build();
mDetector.receiveFrame(outputFrame);
```

All the code can be found in [CameraSource.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java)