# How can we share one camera between two application in android?

Tags: android

How can we share one camera between two applications at the same time .
Like i used camera in one application at that time second is release camera when camera release one at that time second application used camera.
if is it possible than give me suggestion.

Note: when i will release camera,because i am not able to get any notification camera is running or not other application.

Thanks

Comment: A duplicate question of it...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588869/running-2-instances-of-the-camera-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 1):

flat no ~ if you do not close the camera it leaks..... wont work but what you can do is close the camera and save the image to a file and share the file - dont exactly know how yet but i know it can be done with a file + probably other ways

docs are very clear about this