# Android: Thumbnail

Tags: android, thumbnails

Is it possible to extract a Video Thumbnail using other frames than the first frame? Usually the first frame of a Video File is a black screen so I'm thinking its better to use other frame number or a frame anywhere in the middle of a video file that is not a black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at ThumbnailUtils at this page:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html

That should help.

Comment: I've read that and there's nothing there that help me to get a thumbnail other than the first frame.

Comment: Take a look at this conversation: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893072/getting-frames-from-video-image-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893072/getting-frames-from-video-image-in-android). They have mentioned a lot of options which might help you get to valid frame. After that, use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap..)` method to get to a thumbnail.