# How can I show a preview picture after taking a video using MediaRecorder?

Tags: android, video, preview, mediarecorder

I am using MediaRecorder and a SurfaceView to create a custom video camera app. After the user has clicked a stop button, I'd like to show the user a preview of the video (maybe the first or last frame). Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but check this:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893072/getting-frames-from-video-image-in-android

Answer (score 1):

for future references. It's possible to use the

```
surfaceHolder.getSurface().freeze();
```

to hold the last frame.