# SurfaceView freezes for 2 seconds when taking picture with back camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I know this seems a duplicate question to https://stackoverflow.com/q/13846967/1665507 But nobody have answered it yet.My problem is also the same.While capturing images, the camera freezes for 2 sec and again the camera preview restarts to take new image. But my requirement is to remove that freezing time i.e images will be captured in the background without disturbing the camera preview.I know its possible because I have already one application installed in my device which do the same as I want.

I am using the following line to take image,

```
preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
```

and the following to restart the preview,

```
preview.camera.startPreview();
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but, I think that is possible to get the image directly from the "preview", so that "takePicture" method needn't to be called (Like getting a frame of a video)

Maybe these answers can help you:
[Getting image from SurfaceView to ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794307/getting-image-from-surfaceview-to-imageview) - 
[Getting frames from Video Image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893072/getting-frames-from-video-image-in-android)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry For accepting it lately.First link serves the purpose :)