# Get RGB data from the android camera in stream

Tags: android

I have a question. How can getting RGB data in stream from camera? Or YUV data from camera and that translate to RGB? tha

Answer (score 7):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html for information on how to set up the camera, then see [Getting frames from Video Image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893072/getting-frames-from-video-image-in-android) to decode the YUV data.

In that last thread there is a link to some code that reads data from the camera continuously, which I will paste [here](http://code.google.com/p/globetrotter/source/browse/trunk/src/com/ece194/globetrotter/CameraActivity.java).

Comment: thanks for help. This question is closed. The problem is solved

Comment: @Ljudmila If you solved it yourself, you may post a solution here too.