# Extracting RGB values from Android camera

Tags: android, camera, stream, rgb

What I'm trying to do is get a stream of RGB values from a picture taken from the Android camera preview.

So I've looked up a tonne of questions on Stackoverflow and tutorials online and I've gotten this far:

Set the following camera properties:

```
        Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int swidth = size.x;
        int sheight = size.y;

        param.setPreviewSize(sheight, swidth);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        param.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);

        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

The `param.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);` is for compatibility on all devices.

Then I have:

```
    jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                int[] rgbs = new int[swidth*sheight]; //from above code
                decodeYUV(rgbs, data, swidth, sheight);
                for(int i = 0; i<rgbs.length; i++)
                    System.out.println("RGB: " + rgbs[i]);
```

where `decodeYUV()` is the method given [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893072/getting-frames-from-video-image-in-android). I've tried using both answers (methods), and I get similar results. This means it must be working, I'm just doing something wrong.

Now, I'm assuming it is in the format ARGB.

I get the following stream of output from the above code:

```
RGB: -16757489
RGB: -16059990
RGB: -9157
RGB: -49494
RGB: -2859008
RGB: -7283401
RGB: -4288512
RGB: -3339658
RGB: -6411776
RGB: -13994240
RGB: -16750475
RGB: -16735438
RGB: -14937280
RGB: -3866455
RGB: -16762040
RGB: -16714621
RGB: -11647630
RGB: -37121
...
...
```

How do I extract RGB values from this, in the form `R/G/B = [0..255]`?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is ARGB then:

```
int argb = rgbs[i];
int a = ( argb >> 24 ) & 255;
int r = ( argb >> 16 ) & 255;
int g = ( argb >> 8 ) & 255;
int b = argb & 255;
```

The `>>` operator shifts the int to the right, and the `&&` is a boolean and which masks the last eight bits for the result.

Comment: This has certainly helped (assuming you meant `&` and not `&&`). I am getting RGB values but not the correct ones unfortunately. It always seems to average out around 120/120/120 give or take, even when I take a pure black picture. I also get Array Out of Bounds inside my decode function. Any ideas why this may be happening? I have been following precise steps.

Comment: Hard to tell why you get an exception in decode... you didn't post it. Thanks for pointing out the typo -- fixed.